# wrong answer when devide double

Tags: java

I need to get the ratio of 342/556 .
I tried with below.
double hw_ratio=(double)342.0/556.0 
but this gives me wrong answer.(1.6257309941520468)

Comment: Whereas the answer you expected is?

Comment: Please show the code where `double hw_ratio=(double)342.0/556.0` gives you an answer of 1.62[...]. I'd be astonished if you could reproduce that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done it the wrong way round.

```
556/342 = 1.62573....

342/556 = 0.615107....
```