# get only two digit after decimal point

Tags: java, double, decimal

My source code is:

```
public static double roundDown(double d) {

    double value = Math.floor(d * 1e2) / 1e2;

    if(Double.toString(value).contains("."))
        return value;
    else
        return Double.parseDouble(Double.toString(value)+".00");

}
```

when I pass `37187.200000` then output comes `37187.19` and I want it `37187.20`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wrong answer when devide double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296069/wrong-answer-when-devide-double)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: This error is cause by *digital aproximation* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display two digit after decimal point, then simply you can round off like:

```
public static String roundDown(double d) {
    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    return f.format(d);
}
```

But if you want to store 37187.20 in variable of type "double", then it is not possible because double is stored in binary. So it is meaningless to save trailing zeros. This will remove non-significant zeros.

```
public static double roundDown(double d) {
    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    return Double.parseDouble(f.format(d));
}
```